# Does React have an equivalent to Vue.set()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Does React have an equivalent to Vue.set() (aka this.$set)?
It enables Vue to update an object and add reactivity to a property (instead of replacing the entire object).

Answer (score 6):

React doesn't have [Vue's reactivity features](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) and doesn't detect deep changes in state object.

React solely relies on state immutability, i.e. a state is expected to be a new object after it's updated.

In Vue:

```
Vue.set(vm.foo, 'bar', 1);
```

Correct way in React:

```
// just setState for useState hook
this.setState(state => ({
  ...state,
  foo: {
    ...state.foo,
    bar: 1
  }
}));
```

Incorrect way in React:

```
this.state.foo.bar = 1;
this.setState(this.state); // or this.forceUpdate();
```

This will update the component but may not work as expected in child components that rely on immutable state. This won't work with `useState` hook because it relies on immutable state.

Third-party libraries can be used to make the immutability of React state easier ([Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/example-setstate)), or even replace it with mutable state ([MobX](https://blog.cloudboost.io/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e)). MobX works similarly to Vue reactivity (descriptor getter/setter in Vue 2, `Proxy` in Vue 3).

Comment: What would be the circumstances where it would not work in child components?

Comment: @wsyq1n This happens when a child is pure (PureComponent or memo) that isn't rerendered if properties are the same, `<OptimizedComp foo={this.state.foo} />`.

Answer (score -1):

React have State property like Vue.set. it just re-renders the component and using observable technology(diff algorithm) and update only changed element instead of whole DOM update...

Comment: the question is not about React

Comment: please read "Does React have an equivalent to Vue.set() (aka this.$set)? "  React have state mechanism which is equivalent to Vue.set